# Subscribe method from assembly to an event in my application

Tags: c#, events, .net-assembly

Let's say I have an event, declared as so:

```
public class OnGooseHonkEvent{
    public delegate void OnGooseHonk();

    public static event OnGooseHonk OnGooseHonkEvent;
}
```

And then in an assembly compiled to a dll, I have the following code:

```
namespace ExampleMod
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }
        public void OnGooseHonk()
        {
            UntitledGooseAPI.Log("Goose Honked");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I be able to go about subscribing `ExampleMod.Class1.OnGooseHonk` to `OnGooseHonkEvent.OnGooseHonkEvent`? And it has to be done with the Assembly module, as I am loading all assemblies from a directory programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be a little confused the way the `OnGooseHonkEvent` class is setup. Changing the delegate to a method that can be called on the object, and setting up the OnGooseHonkedEvent as a `Eventhandler<EventArgs>` instead of an `event`, I got this:

```
public class OnGooseHonkEvent
{
    // Calling this will notify every event subscriber the goose has honked
    public void HonkTheGoose()
    {
        OnGooseHonkedEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnGooseHonkedEvent;
}

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        OnGooseHonkEvent.OnGooseHonkedEvent += OnGooseHonk;
    }

    public void OnGooseHonk(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UntitledGooseAPI.Log("When any instance of OnGooseHonkEvent calls the HonkTheGoose() method, this should get fired");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought of this method, but I didn't want to use it as I wanted all the subscribing to be done outside of the DLL, as this project will be a mod loader, but if this is the best way to do it, I guess I'll go with it. Thanks!